# render text in GDI

Tags: c#, .net

using(C# .NET) how to render text in GDI. Let me explain little briefly, when a user types text in 'textBox' the text has to get displayed on the same window. This has to get done in GDI **not** GDI+ or ......"AND IT HAS TO GET DONE IN Windows7 and later it'll get installed on Windows Server 2008" So any HELP please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: GDI would only be useful in systems prior to Windows XP, where GDI+ was introduced.  Are you really designing for Windows 98 / Windows 2000?

Comment: Why do you need to use GDI rather than GDI+?

Comment: @DarkBobG: I'm pretty sure that installing the .NET Framework (which would be required for any .NET application) on those older systems would also install GDI+ support.

Comment: @Cody Yeah, I was thinking that as well.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

In c# the function is `Graphics.DrawString`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
the framework is abstracting the GDI functions.
Even if you use a very aged OS, from the DrawString documentation:

*Platform Requirements:
Platforms: **Windows 98, Windows NT 4.0, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 2000,** Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional, Windows Server 2003 family*

Comment: No, that's not correct. `Graphics.DrawString` uses GDI+ internally. You need [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext.aspx) to use GDI.

Comment: @Cody so can we say the msdn doc snipped is wrong ? Anyway, as an abstracting layer the framework should take care on implementing DrawString correctly in any platform, or signal otherwise that is incompatible.

Comment: No, MSDN is right. As I mentioned in a comment, installing the .NET Framework will also install GDI+ on any supported machine. It's the part that you added that's wrong. MSDN doesn't say *anything* about `Graphics.DrawString` using GDI functions internally. You made that part up.